# how can i get line with c compiler ignore my code

Tags: c, visual-studio, input, stdio

If i input

> "insert 2 43" ==> insert(2 43);
>
> "del 2" ==> del(2);
>
> "show" ==> show();

I don't know what wrong with this code.

```
char str[100];
int index;
char* str_data;
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", str);
char* ptr = strtok(str, " ");
ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
index = atoi(ptr);
ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
str_data = ptr;

printf("%s", str_data);

if (str[0] == 'i')
    insert(lk, index, str_data);
else if (str[0] == 'd')
    del(lk, index);
else
    show(lk);
```

My code ignore `gets`, `fgets`, `gets_s`, `scanf("%[^\n]s", str)`.

I don't know

Comment: Could you post the output of the code if possible? I am not sure how your implementation of strtok is working as well.

Comment: You do not check whether `strtok` returns `NULL`..